# How wide is the arc which the Spy can perform a backstab?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

Can anyone provide facts or stats on how wide at the back of an enemy player which a Spy can perform a successful backstab?

Personally, I manage to inflict one at the side (90 deg, side-stab?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

180°

Also keep in mind that you don't need to actually face the same direction as the victim, as long as you hit the back area.

There's more info at the [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Backstab)

Comment: And once you account for lag, there's no telling where your attack will end up. The eponymous 'facestab'.

Comment: Quite right, with lag your knife becomes a construction of quantum physics, tunneling through the opponent and hitting them from the other side, in the equally annoying failstab. And let's not even get into the not-quite-failstabs where the opponent randomly turns around at the last second.

Comment: Also remember that the 'back' of an enemy isn't necessarily their actual back - it's just the reverse side of the enemy, which can vary where the 'back' is considerably.  As an example, the Heavy has a very tilted model, and the middle of his 'back' is actually his shoulder when he's holding the mini-gun or shotgun.